# Limit a processes CPU usage - methods?

Tags: linux, process

I'd like to limit the CPU usage of a process to, say, 10%.

One way this could be done is running the process for 6 continuous seconds every minute and pausing it the rest of the time.

I'm not looking to change the process priority with nice.

Answer (score 6):

[cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) (newer [github link here](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit)) seems to be the tool for the job - it lets you control the processor usage of a process by PID, process name or absolute location, and set its processor usage in terms of percentage of total.

From the docs on the sourceforge page -

**Examples of use**

Limit the process 'bigloop' by executable name to 40% CPU:

```
cpulimit --exe bigloop --limit 40
cpulimit --exe /usr/local/bin/bigloop --limit 40
```

Limit a process by PID to 55% CPU:

```
cpulimit --pid 2960 --limit 55
```

Launch a process by command line and limit it to 40% (in development version only!):

```
cpulimit --limit 40 /etc/rc.d/rc.boinc start
```

Cyberciti.biz has a [howto](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/) that also indicates you maybe able to use

```
-p : Process PID.
-e : Process name.
-l : percentage of CPU allowed from 0 to 100.
-P: absolute path name of the executable program file.
```

Instead of --exe and so on.

And that for multi processors, you should set the percentage based off 100 * number of cores - so a dual system can allow percentages up to 150, and a quad core can allow up to 200

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't specified your operational system, I will just put here an option for Windows and another one for Linux:

**For Linux:**

Use [Stress](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/):

> stress is a deliberately simple workload generator for POSIX systems.
>   It imposes a configurable amount of CPU, memory, I/O, and disk stress
>   on the system. It is written in C, and is free software licensed under
>   the GPLv2.
>
> Here is an example invocation: a load average of four is imposed on
>   the system by specifying two CPU-bound processes, one I/O-bound
>   process, and one memory allocator process.

```
   $ stress --cpu 2 --io 1 --vm 1 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s --verbose
   stress: info: [9372] dispatching hogs: 2 cpu, 1 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
   stress: dbug: [9372] (243) using backoff sleep of 12000us
   stress: dbug: [9372] (262) setting timeout to 10s
   stress: dbug: [9372] (285) --> hogcpu worker 9373 forked
   stress: dbug: [9372] (305) --> hogio worker 9374 forked
   stress: dbug: [9372] (325) --> hogvm worker 9375 forked
   stress: dbug: [9372] (243) using backoff sleep of 3000us
   stress: dbug: [9372] (262) setting timeout to 10s
   stress: dbug: [9372] (285) --> hogcpu worker 9376 forked
   stress: dbug: [9375] (466) hogvm worker malloced 134217728 bytes
   stress: dbug: [9372] (382) <-- worker 9374 signalled normally
   stress: dbug: [9372] (382) <-- worker 9373 signalled normally
   stress: dbug: [9372] (382) <-- worker 9375 signalled normally
   stress: dbug: [9372] (382) <-- worker 9376 signalled normally
   stress: info: [9372] successful run completed in 10s
```

**For Windows:**

Use [BES – Battle Encoder Shirase 1.4.5 / 1.5.2](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/):

> Free software that controls per-process CPU usage. “Active” software
>   CPU cooler.  BES is a small tool that throttles the CPU usage for the
>   process you “target”: for instance, you can limit the CPU usage of a
>   process which would use CPU 100%, down to 50% (or any percentage you’d
>   like). With this, you can use other programs comfortably while doing
>   something CPU-intensive in the background.
>
> By limiting the CPU load, you can also cool down your CPU immediately
>   when it happens to get too hot. It’s an “active” software CPU cooler.
>   Conventional soft-coolers save CPU energy by making CPU sleep when it
>   is idle. They passively wait until CPU gets idle. BES is more
>   aggressive: it cools CPU by making the “heating” process slow down,
>   i.e. periodically forcing CPU to be idle for a short time. (But you
>   should install a better hardware cooler if you often need to use BES
>   for this purpose. Actually, the first thing you should try is to
>   remove dust around your heat sink (See below). Active soft-cooling
>   might be an interesting hack, but it's just a workaround after all. On
>   the other hand, if your application uses CPU 100% meaninglessly, let
>   BES do the job!)

[image]

You could also automate it using Windows command-line:

> The following command line tells BES to watch target.exe, and—when
>   target.exe starts running—throttle its CPU usage so that target.exe
>   will be only allowed to use CPU (100 − percentage) % at most:

```
"C:\path\to\bes.exe" "D:\path to\target.exe" [percentage] [--minimize]
```

> Optionally, you can use an integer between 1 and 99 as percentage. If
>   percentage is omitted or invalid, the last known valid percentage for
>   target.exe is automatically used (if this is the first time to target
>   target.exe, the default reduction 33% will be applied, unless
>   percentage is specified). Note that, when started from command line,
>   BES will Watch/Limit the target, not just Limit it.

Comment: Battle Encoder Shirase is the coolest name for a software ever

Comment: What does `stress` have to do with this question?  It adds new processes, which consume a fixed amount of processor time, but the question wanted to limit an existing application.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows:** (*This is just an expansion to @Diogo 's answer.*)

As a Windows user wanting to just click on a single shortcut to have the desired target program run at the desired CPU throttle automatically, I found that it required a bit more steps involving a batch file and some clarification needed with regards to how exactly to implement the [percentage] and [--minimize] portions within the suggested command line:

```
"C:\path\to\bes.exe" "D:\path to\target.exe" [percentage] [--minimize]
```

The method I ended up using  is as follows.
Make a Windows [batch file](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/),
create a file with a text editor and name it as "[name].bat" (e.g.: something.bat).
Within the file have the following typed out:

```
@echo off 
start "" "C:\path\to\bes.exe" "D:\path to\target.exe" 90 -m
start "" "D:\path to\target.exe"
```

where:

- start "", allows both the [BES](http://mion.faireal.net/BES/) and target program to run [at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010834/how-to-run-multiple-dos-commands-in-parallel).
- "C:\path\to\bes.exe" is the exact path to the BES program within
  the quotes,
- "D:\path to\target.exe" is the exact path to the program you want to throttle CPU with. within the quotes,
- **90** is a percentage of reduction, in this case means reducing the CPU limit to 100-**90** = 10%
- -m is to start up the BES program minimized (as per BES instructions: "*The --minimize option, or -m for short, tells BES to start as minimized (sent to the system tray).*"

Then double-clicking the resulting .bat file will run the target program while automatically be throttled to the desired CPU level with BES.