# CPU Limitation by a process in linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, cpu-usage, cpu-throttling

So I have this lovely tool I wrote. It runs a whole bunch of simultaneous network operations but nothing INTENSIVE.

For some reason on Linux it ends up consuming a lot of CPU cycles and the UI freezes.

This problem does not happen on Windows.

Can I limit CPU time for the process similar to priority setting but with more precision?

How would you even express that?

I'm thinking something like what Virtual Containers do where you allot so many cores but more directed at a process on the host operating system specifically on Fedora Linux.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/442970/limit-a-processes-cpu-usage-methods

Comment: You might invest some time in examining why your tool does that, as you're the author.

Comment: Its node. Its doing that because the pipe checks for network comm consistently and this is out of my control. works fine when its not starved for throughput but fast and slow networks alike screw it up.